# How do I create a loop for a c# hangman game?

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I've made this hangman game but the only problem is I can't figure out which simple loops (For,While, or Do While) I should use to make the program give the user three chances to answer correctly or keep on repeating if they do answer correctly. I was wondering if anyone could guide me in the right direction?

```
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play a game?");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();

        if (answer == "no")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Exit Program");
        }


        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (answer == "yes")
        {   
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Hangman");

            string[] array1 = new string[10];
            array1[0] = "hello";
            array1[1] = "swami";
            array1[2] = "zebra";
            array1[3] = "rainbow";
            array1[4] = "camp";
            array1[5] = "unicycle";
            array1[6] = "trivia";
            array1[7] = "hockey";
            array1[8] = "charlie";
            array1[9] = "canada";

            Random word = new Random();

            int mynumber = word.Next(0, 10);

            char[] array2 = array1[mynumber].ToCharArray();


            char[] array3 = new char[array2.Length];

            Console.WriteLine(array2);

            for (int i = 0; i < array2.Length; i++)
            {
                array3[i] = '*';
            }

            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine(array3);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);

            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            int number = 1;
            number = number + 1;

            Console.WriteLine(" Guess a letter");
            char letter = Char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(" ");

            for (int i = 0; i < array2.Length; i++)
            {
                if (letter == array2[i])
                {
                    Console.Write(letter);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }                    
            }               

            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/HangMan-C-version-e0d17f1b

Comment: A `for` loop runs over a set of numbers, incrementing a variable each loop.  A `while` loop runs *as long as* (thanks @TyCobb) some criteria inside the loop is met.  A `do while` does the same as the `while` but tests the criteria at the end of the loop instead of the beginning.  Which you use depends on what you want to do.

Comment: You need to increment the number only when the letter is wrong; a while loop should be fine (do-while would work too; no difference in this case).  For would work too but it's confusing.

Comment: There's nothing you can do with one that you couldn't do with the others so it's basically a matter of style and what's easiest to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Step back from the details of the code for a moment and consider the logic of the game and how the loop would be expressed in human language.

You essentially have two loops:

1. Repeatedly ask for input within a game.
2. Repeatedly play a game.

If we were to nest those loops within each other in human language pseudo-code, it might look like this:

```
while (player wishes to play again)
  playGame()
```

and within `playGame()`:

```
while (game isn't over)
  playTurn()
```

If you already have the code to conduct a "turn" of the game (the player guesses, the guess is determined to be correct or incorrect, etc.) then all you really need to do is define those conditions.

```
game isn't over
```

You can maintain a simple boolean flag for this.  Something like:

```
bool gameIsOver = false;
```

On any given turn, check the logic of the game.  Has the player won?  Display a message and set the flag to `true`.  Has the player lost?  Same response, just a different message.  So the loop ends up being something like:

```
bool gameIsOver = false;
while (!gameIsOver)
{
    // perform turn logic
    // when a turn ends the game, set gameIsOver to true
}
```

The same concept can then be applied to the outer loop.  That one needs to define:

```
player wished to play again
```

So you might structure it something like:

```
bool continueWithAnotherGame = true;
while (continueWithAnotherGame)
{
    // play a game

    // ask the user if they would like to play again
    // set continueWithAnotherGame based on the user's reply
}
```

The physical keywords used to construct the loop become a lot more straightforward once the semantic structure of the loop has been defined.  From there you can focus more on the details.  For example, you say that a game has 3 "strikes".  That doesn't necessitate the use of a counter within a `for` loop, you can use a separate counter.  Something like:

```
bool gameIsOver = false;
int strikes = 0;
while (!gameIsOver)
{
    // perform turn logic

    // if the turn is a fail, increment strikes

    //   if strikes is greater than or equal to 3, set gameIsOver to true

    // else if the turn is a pass, continue

    //   if the game is solved, set gameIsOver to true
}
```

Comment: Correct, although I'd point out that do-while and for implementations are equally possible (if harder to read).

Comment: @emodendroket: Any loop structure would work.  A `for` would also work, potentially with no step operation and a different conditional check.  (Which would also be harder to read, of course.)

Comment: Right, yeah.  I only mentioned it because the OP seems to wonder which one he has to use and I thought it'd be helpful to understand that they're all formally equivalent.